# Invalid opcode on estimateGas

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, gas-estimate, invalid-opcode

This is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Test {
    struct TestStruct {
        bytes32 name;
        mapping(uint => address) tesMapping;
    }

    TestStruct[] public testStructs;

    function Test(bytes32[] names) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            testStructs[i] = TestStruct(names[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using web3 v1.0. I create a new contract instance with:

```
c = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, from, { 
    data: data
});
```

where abi, from and data are defined in the right way previously.

When I try to estimate the gas needed for deploy in this way:

```
c.deploy({ 
    data: data, 
    arguments: myArgs
}).estimateGas(console.log);
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
```

If I delete the body of the constructor (I leave the constructor empty), I get `null`.

Is there something wrong in the for loop in the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing past the end of your array.

```
TestStruct[] public testStructs;

function Test(bytes32[] names) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        testStructs[i] = TestStruct(names[i]);
    }
}
```

`testStructs` is a dynamically-sized array with an initial size of 0. The first iteration of the loop, you attempt to write to `testStructs[0]`, which is out of bounds.

Use `push` instead:

```
TestStruct[] public testStructs;

function Test(bytes32[] names) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        testStructs.push(TestStruct(names[i]));
    }
}
```